# PHP only display first sub menu, not one for each menu if variable isset

Tags: php, loops

Ok, I hope this makes sense. So I am building a shop, a constant element throughout the shop is the shop side navigation. This is a horizontal menu that shows the main categories as headers.

When you land on the main shop page, it will prompt you to select a category. On this page only the main category headers are displayed, like so:

Cat1
Cat2
Cat3
Cat4
Cat5

However when you select a category it will redirect to that category page, and the side navigation menu will change slightly. And display the sub-menu for that category and only that category, so for example if you clicked Cat1 it would look like this:

Cat1
 subCat1
 subCat2
 subCat3
Cat2
Cat3
Cat4
Cat5

Sorry about the basic examples. My problem is that I can't seem to make only that sub-menu loop for one Category, either non of them display or the same sub-menu is looped for all the Categories.

Here is by side navigation code:

```
<div id="shopcontentl">
   <div id="shopnavigation">
    <?php
    $navGet = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Categories");
    while ($navHead = mssql_fetch_array($navGet)) { 
    ?>
      <a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $navHead['CatID']; ?>"><?php echo $navHead['CatName']; ?></a>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id'] > 0)) {
    ?>
    <div class="subnav">
    <?php
    $subnavGet = mssql_query("SELECT SubCatName FROM SubCategories WHERE CatID = ".$_GET['id']."");
    while ($subnavHead = mssql_fetch_array($subnavGet)) {
    ?>
      <a href="category.php"><?php echo $subnavHead['SubCatName']; ?></a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I'm pretty sure I am using the loops wrong, but I'm fairly new to PHP, can anyone understand what I'm saying and point me in the correct direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add condition for perticular id as shown below.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id'] > 0) && ($_GET['id']==$navHead['CatID'])) {
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. +1 and will accept when I can. Not sure who down-voted, but I would like to know an explanation.

Comment: You need to show submenu only if current category in loop is same as current category page's id. Daxen's solution is also right.

Answer (score 1):

Just one change

```
<?php
$subnavGet = mssql_query("SELECT SubCatName FROM SubCategories WHERE CatID = ".$navHead['CatID']."");
while ($subnavHead = mssql_fetch_array($subnavGet)) {
?>
```

it is must for sub category because whenever fetch one category and than go to inner loop it have need for master id for particular main category. so we can give that id in to inner loop query.